# I am automating olx ad post for my learning when I go to ad post page

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium Java(Eclipse).  I am automating OLX Site ad post for my learning when I go to add post page at Link: http://www.olx.com.pk/posting/. On this page when I click category drop down a window appears I am unable to get elements on that window. Important:  It is not a new window fancy div is used for it pic is attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3IQG.jpg)

Comment: Could you show us your code and error/exceptions?
I have no idea what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the fancy box and the contents. Please check the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.olx.com.pk/posting/");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='category-breadcrumb-container']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='fancybox-content']//a[@alt='Mobiles']")).click();
```